# How can i do a select from foren table using active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have 2 tables, Accounts and Subscriptions. All the accounts have a subscription and when i do

```
Account.last.subscription.name
  Account Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" ORDER BY "accounts"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  Subscription Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "subscriptions".* FROM "subscriptions" WHERE "subscriptions"."account_id" = 73 LIMIT 1
"free"
```

But i am trying to get all the accounts that are set to free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's scant detail in your question, so we'll have to make some assumptions. Let's assume `Subscription` has a boolean `free` column.

```
# Rails 4
Account.joins(:subscriptions).where(free: true).references(:subscriptions)

# Rails 3
Account.joins(:subscriptions).where('subscriptions.free = ?', true)
```

If we assume `free` is an Account attribute:

```
Account.where(free: true)
```

And if you want to pull up the subscription details:

```
Account.where(free: true).includes(:subscriptions)
```

Comment: Based on the logs, I think the OP uses the `name` attribute to define which instances are free. Doesn't entirely make sense to me.